# Prove $ \lim_{z \to \exp \left(\frac{2 \pi i p}{m !}\right)} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {z}^{n !} = \infty$ (Whittaker-Watson)

Tags: limits, factorial

The following is a problem posed by Lerch in 1885.

**Problem:** For $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p = 0 , 1 , 2 , \ldots , \left(m ! - 1\right)$. Show that

\begin{align}
 \lim_{z \to \exp \left(\frac{2 \pi i p}{m !}\right)} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {z}^{n !} = \infty \\
\end{align}

where the limit $z \to \exp \left(\frac{2 \pi i p}{m !}\right)$ is taken along a radial line (with the argument $\frac{2 \pi i p}{m !}$) through that point.

**Thoughts**: Would I need to show that $m !$ and $n !$ line up just right so that all the powers of $z$ constructively superpose and diverge to $\infty$? Would I have to quote a result from number theory?

Comment: Let $w$ be the point where the limit is taken and $f(z)$ the series. Since the limits is radial you can write the limit as $\lim_{r\to1^-}f(rw)$. For all $n>m$ we have that $(rw)^{n!}=r^{n!}$. Therefore, $f(rw)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}(rw)^n+\sum_{n=m+1}r^{n!}$. The first sum has a limit. You only need to look at the limit of $\sum_{n=m+1}r^{n!}$. This you can say tends to infinity by [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem#Remarks) or prove it directly.